# Is it possible to make HttpClient ignore invalid ETag header in response?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on an application which makes a web service request using the `HttpClient` API to a third party service over which I have no control. The service seems to respond to requests with an `ETag` HTTP header containing an invalid value according to the HTTP specification (the value is not enclosed in quotation marks). This causes the `HttpClient` to fail with a `System.FormatException`.

In this case I am not interested in the `ETag` header and would like to be able to ignore the invalid value. *Is it possible to do this using `HttpClient`?*

I would prefer to use the `HttpClient` API over `WebClient` or `WebRequest` since this particular use case requires me to use a SOCKS proxy which is a lot simpler when using `HttpClient`.

Comment: What if create delegating handler and remove that header inside it?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new Handler());
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.example.local");
        var r = client.GetAsync("").Result;
        Console.WriteLine(r.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(r.Headers.ETag);
    }
}

class Handler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var headerName = "ETag";
        var r = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        var header = r.Headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == headerName);
        var updatedValue = header.Value.Select(x => x.StartsWith("\"") ? x : "\"" + x + "\"").ToList();
        r.Headers.Remove(headerName);
        r.Headers.Add(headerName, updatedValue);
        return r;
    }
}
```

My response headers:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2013 16:49:29 GMT
>
> FiddlerTemplate: True
>
> Content-Length: 310
>
> Content-Type: image/gif
>
> ETag: rtt123

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Even though the delegating handlers executes, the call to `base.SendAsync()` fails with the same `FormatException` as earlier.